# Standalone application which has confidential certificate & data

Tags: java, swing, security, jar, certificate

I have created one Java project having confidential certificate and information, I want to wrap this project and one secure jar.

How to create Java standalone application which has confidential certificate and confidential data?

Comment: I suggest not to do it. It's no longer confidential if you give it away.

Comment: Its legacy project - i have to make secure jar , Thanks for suggestion but I have to do :(

Comment: You can make a secure jar (by encrypting it with a strong key) but then you cannot run it. The moment you give someone the key required to run (decrypt) it, it's no longer secure. You will only be able to get security by obscurity - but a smart person will be able to get around that.

Comment: The only thing you can do is lie and claim that you've come up with a secure solution, but smart people will realize that it's not true. So you have the option of saying "it can't be done" or risk being discovered as a fraud. I recommend telling the truth and saying that a truly secure solution can't be achieved, so the requirements need to be rethought.

Comment: You could store the certificate and data outside the jar. So you have the jar file with the executable code and then a second file, which contains the confidential things. That seconds file has been encrypted. The jar / your program contains logic to decrypt that file and it will also contain the key to decrypt. So you need to obfuscate your code and don't just save the key but "calculate" it in many different places with fuzzy code, so people looking at your obfuscated code will not manage to get the key. But this is still not a 100% secure solution.

Comment: @Korashen that's just security by obscurity nonsense. If we're talking about security, we have to assume that it's not the neighbour's 12 year old boy that's trying to retrieve the keys.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, you are absolutly right. The more you obfuscate it with nonsense, the more annoying it becomes to analyse and trace. Yet not impossible to do.

Comment: @Korashen that's not necessarily true. You can spend time trying to make complex scenarios of obfuscation, yet the attacker may be able to do something as simple as reading the memory while running the program, essentially bypassing everything. Obfuscation is *really* inefficient, except when the attacker is unskilled.

Comment: If you care enough, you could look into hardware encryption devices (they exist in all shapes and sizes, *and prices*). Some of them support the Java crypto APIs. If you generate the private key/certificate within the device and the device does all the signing and doesn't under any circumstance give out the private key, then you have something that's quite secure. Even in that case, a sufficiently funded organisation (think big company or intelligence agency) can probably get enough information to crack the encryption if they get their hands on the physical device.

Answer (score 1):

> How to create Java standalone application which has confidential certificate and confidential data?

- Obfuscate as much of the data and certificate as possible.
- Move, don't copy, the Jar onto a hard disk or flash drive. Ensure it is the **only** copy remaining.
- Put the hard disk / flash drive in a strong safe.
- Drop the safe in the ocean over the Mariana Trench.

Hopefully the safe will then be too deep to retrieve. If it can be retrieved, the safe can be cracked. Assuming the storage device inside it has not been destroyed by water, pressure or cold, it can be read. If storage media can be read, the Jar can be reverse engineered - even if obfuscated.

Really the only option for keeping the certificate confidential is to put the bulk of the app. on a server, and provide either a desktop app. or web-app that is simply an interface to it. The only way to keep the data secure is to also store it on the server, though that will require ensuring the security of the data while being transmitted from server to client & back, and while loaded in the client side app.